# Windows XP x64 hangs at welcome screen

Tags: windows-xp, boot, 64-bit, freeze

The problem is that when I boot on Windows XP (x64), which worked very great for a great amount of time, the mouse pointer and the welcome screen appears but then after waiting hour or so nothing changes and it won't proceed to the Log On screen where I should enter my password. I have Windows 8.1 (Update 1) also installed. So here are the things I tried (without success):

Actions:

1. Booting in all kinds of safe mode.
2. Changing AHCI to IDE in BIOS settings.
3. Changing primary Graphics Device from PCI-E to onboard in BIOS settings.
4. Replacing the `C:\Windows\System32\Config\SYSTEM` registry with an older backed up copy.
5. Deleting the `HKLM\SYSTEM\MountedDevices` registry entry.
6. Checking the system disk for errors (No errors were found).

Result of them:

Nothing changes - Windows XP still boots up successfully but hangs on this screen:

[image: The hang screen]

I have totally lost hope what the problem can be. If it was some bugged start-up services then swapping the registry with an very absolute copy of them would fix the problem, right? Otherwise - you see the problem is not in the drive as when I checked it - no errors were found. Also I have changed a lot of BIOS settings with no result as well. And lastly I've also tried to replace `WinLogon.exe` with `Explorer.exe` but then the system refuses to launch it and automatically restarts. I have also tried testing an early `MessageBoxW` call, before the `WinLogon.exe` `WinMain` function but with the same result stated above - the system crashed.

I'm also trying to debug `WinLogon.exe` to see the problem in real-time but unfortunately I have a lot of bad time with this as it seems it can't be done locally so I need either to buy an USB debug cable for a lot of money or an PCI-E Firewire card. But I should maybe create a different question for this topic.

Comment: I'm not sure anyone can help with that. You know "without looking inside". I hope I'm wrong on that, though. However, if you can recall what was the last time it work, that might help you figuring out which update/change step killed your XP. You could also try the "repair" stuff but I wouldn't rely on that

Comment: @Mark  You never heard of a Windows XP Repair Installation? It is EXTREMELY good, much more versatile than the Windows 7 one. Don't just say 'repair stuff'. You have no idea how ambiguous that is. The Repair Installation (not recovery console), is the thing to do.  http://www.michaelstevenstech.com/XPrepairinstall.htm

Comment: @barlop You misunderstood. I meant it would not help with asker's issue. He installs XP, make changes, then it dies at one point. Even if he repairs, will do the same thing and XP goes down again... So he has to figure out what EXACTLY is the reason of XP getting compromised. Reading it back I might have been sloppy expressing myself, though.

Comment: I had a [similar problem](http://superuser.com/q/868267/186753). If you still have the problem you can try my solution. However, it's just a variation of your failed attempt 4.

Answer (score -1):

The Answer Is http://www.michaelstevenstech.com/XPrepairinstall.htm

Repair Installation. It installs XP over XP, overwriting all the important files. That is not the recovery console.

Your data should be fine.  It  touchees c:\windows and might work in  c:\program files and works on your registry. Any other folder like c:\blah is left alone.  I don't think it removes anything from c:\documents and settings.

XP's repair installation is MUCH more versatile than the Windows 7 repair installation. The Windows 7 one only works when you can get into windows. The XP one works even when you can't get into Windows. You're lucky you're fixing XP!

Another option is a parallel installation, installing XP to another directory on the same partition. Then copy the files over..

Another option, not necessarily so easy, is you could make a new partition and install to that and copy files over but you may need to shrink a partition to make space, so that's not so easy..

Try a repair installation first.  But consider a parallel installation e.g. if that fails.