# Debugging not-loading Windows XP x64

Tags: windows-xp, windows-vista, kernel, firewire, debugger

The question is related to this one: [Windows XP x64 hangs at welcome screen](https://superuser.com/questions/736230/windows-xp-x64-hangs-at-welcome-screen). So I want to debug `WinLogon.exe` through Windows Kernel-Debugger remotely using an 1394 (Fire Wire) port on the system asked for fix above. If you have read the linked question you'll know that I can only access the XP system files through my primary OS (Windows 8.1 (Update 1)).

So to set up the debugging on the target computer I should:

1. Specify debug parameter in `Boot.ini` with `/debugport=1394` (as per [MDSN documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff556253(v=vs.85).aspx)).
2. Instruct the debugger to break on `WinLogon.exe` ([Debugging WinLogon](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff541428%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)).

Am I right for those steps? Also I'm especially worried that the target computer doesn't have an 1394 port and I'm going to buy an external PCI one. The question is will the Kernel-Debugger recognise it and how could I instruct to use it. As I don't have access to the Desktop and the Found New Hardware program wouldn't run!!

Also I'm thinking of connecting an laptop for the host computer which don't have an Fire Wire port either. What connector would you suggest to buy for - it has only USB ports?

The host computer runs Windows Vista by the way. And the target computer is an PC with a [B75M-GL](http://www.asrock.com/mb/Intel/B75M-GL/) motherboard so the 1394 controller will be directly placed on its PCI slots.