# Windows XP hangs just before displaying login screen

Tags: windows, windows-xp, freeze, login

I messed up my registry using SubInAcl.

When I tried switching user, Windows froze just before displaying login screen.

Then I rebooted the PC, but Windows froze again just before displaying login screen.

When windows is frozen, if I press alt+tab, I can switch between "Log on to windows" and "Windows logon". Choosing "Log on to windows" does nothing. Choosing "Windows logon" does nothing, except making alt+tab stop working.

Booting into safe mode or last known good configuration still produces the same problem.

[image]

Comment: This seems similar to [Windows XP x64 hangs at welcome screen](http://superuser.com/q/736230/186753), but the poster of that question says he tried (more or less) the solution that worked for me, but didn't work for him. So I guess the problems are caused by different things, therefore I posted this other question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it thanks to [hek8981](http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/profile/d0461b38-3c59-4068-8619-02833ae9ddb6)'s post in [Windows hangs just before displaying LOGIN screen, No response to CTRL-ALT-DEL](http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_xp-system/windows-hangs-just-before-displaying-login-screen/2e1c9e21-18ee-4243-bee1-de0b70552845).

These are the steps:

1. Boot into Linux
2. Backup `%windir%\system32\config` somewhere, just in case.
3. Go to `%SystemDrive%\System Volume Information`. This is where restore points are stored.
4. Go to the subfolder which was modified last, but before that problem occurred.
5. Go to the `RPXXX` (`XXX` are some numbers) subfolder which was modified last, but before that problem occurred.
6. Go to the `snapshot` subfolder.
7. Copy the following files to somewhere, removing their prefix:

   - `_REGISTRY_MACHINE_SAM` -> `SAM`
   - `_REGISTRY_MACHINE_SECURITY` -> `SECURITY`
   - `_REGISTRY_MACHINE_SOFTWARE` -> `software`
   - `_REGISTRY_MACHINE_SYSTEM` -> `system`
   - `_REGISTRY_USER_.DEFAULT` -> `default`
8. Move the copied files to `%windir%\system32\config`, overwriting the existing ones.
9. Boot into Windows.

Comment: "Upgrade to a new OS" ;)